# How does a Symmetric CGN handle this scenario?

Tags: connection, sip, portforwarding, nat, scenarios

Client A (behind a NAT) tries to send the same session initiation message to a port on server B from multiple ports, what does the NAT do, does the NAT forward all the ports trough different random ports or does the NAT software sends only one message to the port on server B as it can see that all of them are the same, would it work differently if they were different? I know this is more of a theoretic question than an actual example but I'd like an answer

Answer (score 0):

NAT is not that smart. It will forward all the messages with the public source port set based on whatever algorithm it uses. The public source ports of the two messages will be different.

Some NAT's used to have a thing called an Application Layer Gateway (ALG) included that could detect certain protocols, such as SIP, and change the messages to reflect the public IP address and port set by the NAT. ALG's were a terrible idea and hopefully have disappeared by now which means all your NAT should be doing for SIP is mapping an internal socket to a public one.